# Image animate down javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I know how to fix the animation that goes down only when the image is showing up in the window with jQuery, but now I want to do that with JavaScript. Struggling with that. The image must be fluently go down (+50px for 1.6 seconds). Have googling around, but most of them are done with jQuery I suggest and that is not what I want. Furtermore the animation should start when the scrollTop is between 600px and 800px.

```js
function scrollFunction() {
 var animate = document.getElementById("picture");
 var position = 0;
    var top = 0;
 var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 if(scrollTop > 600 && scrollTop < 800){
  position++;
  animate.style.top = position + "50px";
 } else {
  stop();
 }
}

function stop() {
 clearTimeout(animate);
}
```

```css
#picture {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 top: -5px;
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <h1 class="responsive-h1">Mi<span class="logo-orange"> Pad2</span></h1>
            <p class="edition-title above-text-black">Black Edition</p>
        <img src="Img/picture.jpg" id="picture"/>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n1q3fy8w/

Javascript

```
var imgSlide = document.getElementById('slidedown-image');

var slideDown = setInterval(function() {
  var topVal = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(imgSlide).top, 10);
  imgSlide.style.top = (topVal + 1) + "px";
}, 15);

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( slideDown ); }, 1600);
```

You get the element first, after that you setup a `setInterval` which will basically move our `img` downwards, we then also set a `setTimeout` which after `1600`ms remvoes the `slideDown` interval and the image stops. Your image however may need `position: absolute`.

The above answer will only work in Chrome, this however should work in all browswers

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n1q3fy8w/1/

javascript

```
var imgSlide = document.getElementById('slidedown-image');

var slideDown = setInterval(function() {
  var topVal = parseInt(imgSlide.style.top, 10);
  imgSlide.style.top = (topVal + 1) + "px";
}, 15);

setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( slideDown ); }, 1600);
```

Ok so `getComputedStyle` only works in chrome, so to get this to work on all other browsers, you have to specifically set the `css` property on the element and not via CSS.

When you use javascript to access an element and change its style like so `element.style.bottom = '150px'` the `.style` gets you all of the css values for your inline styles on that element, so any `css` changes on an element that is done via a .css/.less file you can't access via javascript.

So all the above code does is we set a `top: 0` on the element itself and in our code we use `imageSlide.style.top` instead of chrome's `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: This is what the console said aimation.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.

Comment: My bad `getComputedStyle` only works in chrome, basically what you have to do is set the `top` css property to `0` on the element, look at my new answer in a second

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a CSS transition? if you are changing the value of top you should be able to add transition: top 1.6s in your css (to picture). (Then the vendor prefixed versions when you get it working)